# create a JAR containing the classes in the webapp using gradle

Tags: web-applications, jar, war, gradle

I.e. is there any equivalent of [archiveClasses = true setting of maven-war-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/faq.html#attached) for War Graddle task?

Comment: A cursory examination of the [War task documentation](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.War.html) suggests not. You chould probably submit a request for this in the [Gradle issue tracker](http://issues.gradle.org/).

Comment: I [added a simlar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21175585/create-a-jar-containing-classes-and-resources-from-webapp-using-gradle) on a how to do this manually via the jar task

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's [an incantation from Mark Vieira](http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/war-task-should-allow-bundling-classes-into-jar#reply_15200781) that works for me with Gradle 2.2.1:

```
war {  
    classpath = classpath - sourceSets.main.output  
    from (jar) {  
        into 'WEB-INF/lib'  
    }  
}
```