# Create a JAR containing classes and resources from webapp using Gradle

Tags: java, jar, gradle, war

I would like to create a jar from the contents of a WAR using gradle. The result I want is quite like what the [archiveClasses = true setting of maven-war-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/faq.html#attached) does.

I understand that the gradle war plugin doesn't seem to do this (as per [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13359736/create-a-jar-containing-the-classes-in-the-webapp-using-gradle)).

Is there a way to do this manually? Say by manipulating the gradle jar task to collect the required parts from the WEB-INF folder?

When I just use the default jar task it doesn't get the resources from the WEB-INF directory.

The reason I want to do this is because I have modularised a WAR and the modules depend on common resources in the WAR (FreeMarker files in my case). I want to be able to test each module by depending on JAR created from the WAR.

I understand I could also create a "common" jar that held all the resources and have both the WAR and the module depend on this, but it would be more convenient to create a JAR form the WAR as per the maven-war-plugin.

Comment: The Gradle WAR plug-in doesn't seem to have these kinds of features yet; little surprising. I think for the time being you'll be stuck going the common JAR route if you need in the short term. Could try something hacky like calling Gradle's `Exec` task to run a Maven process if you're feeling adventurous.

Comment: It's easy to achieve. What exactly should the Jar contain?

Comment: I want the jar to do it's normal source path (which I'm guessing is sourseSet.main.output and maybe sourceSet.main.resources?) plus the contents of WEB-INF excluding classes and lib as in my case there are resources in directories there. So an example that includes an extra dir and excludes another would be wonderful!

Comment: I tried creating a jar task ("webjar") and calling: from('src/webapp/WEB-INF') { include('freemarker/**') } but then I only get this dir, not the classes or resources from the default sourceSets. Maybe I should add a sourceSet for that one jar task, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this to include both src/main/resources and scr/main/webapp in the root of the created jar file:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        resources {
            srcDirs "src/main/resources", "src/main/webapp"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Should I use this inside the jar task?

Comment: @CarlPritchett No, that should be in the root of the gradle file!

Answer (score 3):

So here is how I solved it (not sure if this is the best way):

```
jar {
    from ("${projectDir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF") {
        include('freemarker/**')
    }
}
```

I also found [this alternative](http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/what_is_best_practice_with_spring_bassed_webapps_junit_and_gradle) in the Gradle forums but I couldn't get the line `resources.srcDir("src/main/webapp").exclude('images/')` to compile, but I really like the idea of somehow just adding to the jar task's default resources directories. 
**Edit**: I think my first example above is as good as it gets.